# Center div inside a div that is in a bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="footer col-md-12">

    <div class="social col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><div id="fb"></div></a>
        <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank"><div id="linkedin"></div></a>
        <a href="http://plus.google.com" target="_blank"><div id="gplus"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is also a div with copyright text, that I can't post. it is before the "social" div. On mobile devices, I am removing the copyright text(via display: none;), and I want to center the social icons, but I am unable to do so. I manage to do it, with margins and percentages, but on a specific resolution only, all other mobile resolutions are broken. Can someone assist me?
Note: I tried changing the xs column width and offset, but no combination managed to center the icons. I am posting the one, that was closest, that I centered with adding some margins.

Comment: Please post the CSS that you are using or have tried.

Comment: `.social { text-align: center;}` or `.footer { text-align: center; }`

Comment: This is what I was using at @media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 500px) {
`div.social {
        position: relative;
        right: 5%;
    }`
@Scott That sort of, kinda works, with column-xs-10 on .social on my mobile phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you just need to use class names in html and css as below

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer col-md-12">
    <div class="copyright col-md-9 col-sm-8">
      copyright information
    </div>
    <div class="social col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a> -
        <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank">Twitter</a> -
        <a href="http://plus.google.com" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.social{
  background:aqua;
  text-align: center;
}
.copyright{
  background:silver;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .copyright {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

and this is the sample : https://jsfiddle.net/Tanbi/asohog47/1/

**PS:** For understanding clearly i used css background colors.

Comment: Marking this as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.social {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I find this works for me in most responsive centering dilemmas (with bootstrap in past times too I believe).

Let us know if this helps?

Comment: I have tried this, but it is fighting with the column widths and can't get it to center. I have managed to center it with setting `col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0` and then the CSS: `.social { text-align: center;}` (as @Scott suggested)